# Paste N Times Based on Column Value Isn't Working

Tags: excel, copy-paste, do-while, vba

Thanks to a [previous post and some excellent direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665824/copy-paste-n-times-based-on-other-cell-values) I was able to create successfully working code for my needs. However, the table/data has changed a bit and I have not yet reached my ultimate goal of iterating the paste function based on another cell's value. I have seen [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099103/excel-2007-vba-copy-rows-x-times-based-on-text-filter) but it has not helped me. I found other resources on [using loops in Excel VBA](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) and created the very simple `Do While` code you see below.

My problem: I cannot get the code to stop looping when it reaches the value from Column F. It finds the first available case and outputs the correct information endlessly without stopping at *n* value and moving on.

Here is a look at the data table:

```
     A    B   C        D     E    F
 R1 Name Num Status   #Orig #Act #Rem
 R2 ABC  032 Complete 22    0    11
 R3 LMN  035 In Prog  25    21   4
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Copy_Pending_Status()

Dim srcrange As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("SIS Agregate")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Center Detail")
Set srcrange = ws2.Range("C2:C61")

For Each Row In srcrange.Cells
    Select Case Row.Value
        Case "In Progress"
            Do While i <= Row.Offset(0, 3).Value
                Set LastCell = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                LastCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = Row.Offset(0, -2).Value
                LastCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Row.Offset(0, -1).Value
                LastCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Not Yet Scanned"
            Loop

        Case "Complete"
            Do While i <= Row.Offset(0, 3).Value
                Set LastCell = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                LastCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = Row.Offset(0, -2).Value
                LastCell.Offset(0, 12).Value = Row.Offset(0, -1).Value
                LastCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Purged"
            Loop
    End Select
Next Row

End Sub
```

I have tried setting the `Do While i <= Row.Offset(0, 3).Value` to `(0,3)` `(0,4)` and `(0,6)` as I am not sure if it is counting the number of columns from "A" as one, "C" as one, or "C" as zero and offset is three (to the right).

I want to note that eliminating the `Do While` and `Loop` lines of code from each case make this function correctly, but only once per row, per case - as opposed to however many times Column F indicates.

Have I oversimplified this and am missing some obvious key information? What change do I need to make to get this little loop to function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing within your loops changes the value of i, and so the "Do While" conditions are always met. You need to iterate through values of i so that eventually the conditions will not be met. At the end of each loop, add:

`i = i + 1`

This will allow it to count how many times the loop has been run and stop after a set number of iterations based on Column F.

You'll also want to re-set i to zero in between each row. Do this between "End Select" and "Next Row":

`End Select
i = 0
Next Row`

Comment: That did the trick! I did, however, have to move `i = 0` to between the `For Each` and `Select Case` rows of code. And I ended up with `i = 1`. Otherwise, this was all I needed.